# Function to find largest area of a rectangle possible (NOT neccessarily axis parallel) from a list of points

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity, dynamic-programming

Input: 2d array of points ((x, y), (x2, y2), ...)
Output: area of largest possible rectangle that has its 4 corners as 4 of the points given.

Note: the rectangle does not have to be parallel to any axis, at least one rectangle is possible to make with the set of points

---

Example 1:
Input:  [[1,2], [2,1], [1,0], [0,1]]
Output: 2
Explanation:
the rectangle looks like this on a 2d plane:

```
2   x
1 x   x
0   x
  0 1 2
```

The side lengths are sqrt(2) each and so the area is 2.

Example 2:
Input:  [[0,1], [2,1], [1,1], [1,0], [2,0]]
Output: 1

Explanation:
The plane:

```
2
1 x x x
0   x x
  0 1 2
```

The only possible rectangle is a square with sides length 1 so the area is 1.

---

I would appreciate any help on solving this problem, honestly I have no clue how to make it more efficient. Is it even possible?

I tried bruteforcing it, i.e checking all possible combinations of 4 points to see if they make a rectangle, then comparing their areas, but it is wayy too slow for large inputs...

Comment: oh yeah, I forgot to mention that there is always at least one possible rectangle. I'll add that and some examples

Comment: Looking at the examples, does that mean that the points always have *integer* coordinates?

Comment: How large are your large inputs?

Comment: Note that it's not clear what it is that you call "bruteforcing". There's a lot of variation on "naive" algorithms for this, and some of them will be a lot more efficient than others. As an obvious optimisation, rather than iterate on every quadruple of points, you could iterate on every triplet of points and check whether they are orthogonal and whether the triangle they form can be completed into a rectangle. For n points this takes you from a n^4  algorithm to a n^3 algorithm, which is still bad but already a huge improvement.

Comment: @trincot yes that is the case.

Comment: @Stef The size of the inputs in the task I was given is very small, so my O(n^4) approach worked, but I do wonder if there is a better solution... I mean one that is less than O(n^2) or equal to that at least

Comment: @jojo_mark I already mentioned how to go from the n^4 bruteforce solution down to a n^3 bruteforce solution with a relatively naive optimisation. You can push this idea further and iterate over pairs of points, and for every pair of points you try to find whether there exist points that comple this pair into a rectangle. Now the main question is "Given a pair of points, how efficiently can you search for points that complete this pair into a rectangle?".

Comment: @jojo_mark Obviously if your points are just kept into a long unordered list with no structure, then everytime you ask "can I complete this triplet into a rectangle" or "can I complete this pair into a rectangle" you have to iterate over the whole list to look for points to complete with, and that's not efficient at all. But if your points are stored into a structure that is easier to search, for instance a quadtree, then it can be much more efficient.

Comment: @jojo_mark In fact if your points all have coordinate integers, then computations are exact, so for the n^3 bruteforce algorithm you can store your points in a simple  hashtable, so that given coordinates (x,y), the question "is (x, y) a point in your set?" can be answered in O(1) time.

Comment: @Stef First of all, thank you for the advice.
Secondly, I am a beginner at this kind of thing, so could you explain to me what is a quadtree and how it can be applied to make this more efficient? Thanks.

Comment: @Stef Ohh I get it, since you would know where the fourth point should go if you already have 3 of them

Comment: May I suggest editting the title from "(NOT NECCESARILY PARRALEL)" to "(not necessarily axis-aligned)"?

Comment: (@Steff oops...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few algorithms in decreasing order of naiveté.

#### Most-naive bruteforce: iterate on quadruplet of points, n^4

- Iterate on quadruplets of points
- For each quadruplet (a, b, c, d) of points, check if (a, b, c, d) forms a rectangle, and calculate its area.

#### Slightly-less-naive bruteforce: iterate on triplets of points, n^3

Because your points all have integer coordinates, calculations are exact. Given three points a, b, c, you can calculate directly the coordinates of the only point d such that a,b,c,d is a rectangle, and check whether d is one of the points in the input list of points.

To check efficiently whether a point is in the list, you should start by building a hashtable from the list, so that this membership check is O(1). In python this is done using `set()`.

#### n^2 solution: searching for parallelograms by building a table of vectors

A quadrilateral a,b,c,d is a parallelogram if and only if the two vectors b-a and d-c are equal, ie if opposite sides ab and dc are parallel and have the same length.

A parallelogram a,b,c,d is a rectangle if and only if the two vectors c-a and d-b are orthogonal, ie iff the diagonals cross at a right angle.

This suggests a pseudo-n^2 algorithm: build a hashtable that maps vectors to the list of pairs of points that make this vector. Then iterate over every vector that corresponds to at least two distinct pairs of points, and check whether the corresponding parallelogram is a rectangle.

```py
from itertools import combinations

class Point(tuple):
    def __add__(self, v):  # point + vector == point
        return Point(x + y for x,y in zip(self, v))
    def __sub__(self, b):  # point - point == vector
        return Vector(x - y for x,y in zip(self, b))
    def __rsub__(self, a): # point - point == vector
        return Point(a).__sub__(self)

class Vector(tuple):
    def __add__(self, v):  # vector + vector == vector
        return Vector(x + y for x,y in zip(self, v))
    def __sub__(self, v):  # vector - vector == vector
        return Vector(x - y for x,y in zip(self, b))
    def __matmul__(self, v):  # dot product: vector @ vector == scalar
        return sum(x * y for x,y in zip(self, v))

def area(a, b, c, d):
    ux, uy = b - a
    vx, vy = d - a
    return abs(ux * vy - vx * uy)  # cross product


def build_vector_table(points):
    table = {}
    for a, b in combinations(points, 2):
        if (b - a)[0] < 0 or (b - a)[0] <= 0 and (b - a)[1] <= 0:
            (a, b) = (b, a)  # Consider only vector ab or ba so that the vector is facing rightwards
        table.setdefault(b - a, []).append((a, b))
    return table

def find_largest_rectangle(points):
    table = build_vector_table(points)
    best_area = 0
    best_rectangle = None
    for v, l in table.items():
        if len(l) >= 2:
            for (a, b), (c, d) in combinations(l, 2):
                if (d - a) @ (c - b) == 0:  # dot product == 0 iff orthogonal
                    if area(a, b, d, c) > best_area:
                        best_area = area(a, b, d, c)
                        best_rectangle = (a, b, d, c)
    return best_area, best_rectangle

examples = [
    [[1,2],[2,1],[1,0],[0,1]],
    [[0,1],[2,1],[1,1],[1,0],[2,0]]
]
examples = [[Point(a) for a in l] for l in examples]

def main():
    for points in examples:
        best_area, best_rectangle = find_largest_rectangle(points)
        print(points)
        # print(build_vector_tables(points))
        print('    best area: ', best_area)
        print('    rectangle: ', best_rectangle)
        print()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

# [(1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1)]
#     best area:  2
#     rectangle:  ((1, 2), (2, 1), (1, 0), (0, 1))
# 
# [(0, 1), (2, 1), (1, 1), (1, 0), (2, 0)]
#     best area:  1
#     rectangle:  ((1, 1), (2, 1), (2, 0), (1, 0))
```

Note that this algorithm is mostly equivalent to the algorithm described in MattTimmermans' answer. However:

- Matt suggests that the inner loop `for (a, b), (c, d) in combinations(l, 2):` is inefficient and can be optimised. Here `l` is a list of parallel pairs of points, and when you take two pairs of points that defines a parallelogram, but instead of iterating over all those possible parallelograms like I did, you can directly see that the largest possible parallelogram will consist of the lowest and highest or rightmost and leftmost pairs
- When building the table, instead of keeping all pairs, Matt only kept pairs (a, b) such that the angle between vector ab and the horizontal axis is between -45° and +45°. He can do that because if (a, b, c, d) is a rectangle, then either ab has an angle between -45 and +45, or ad has an angle between -45 and +45, and we don't need both. Also "ab has an angle between -45 and +45" is equivalent to `abs(by - ay) <= abs(bx - ax)`.

Comment: Wow. Um.
I guess for starters, what is dotproduct exactly? I have no clue it does or how it's used apart from what you mentioned with it checking if 2 lines are orthogonal (how does it check that?).
also I don't understand this line:
table[b - a].setdefault([]).append((a, b))
I don't understand anything about this line honestly.
 Maybe it's too much to ask, but would it be possible to explain it to someone who has no knowledge of vectors at all? (me).
also, thank you very much for going into so much detail in the first place, I never expected to receive this type of answer

Comment: @jojo_mark Yes sorry, I didn't go into a lot of detail. For your first question: dotproduct is the mathematical dot product of two vectors, which in this case is just `dotproduct(u, v) = u.x * v.x + u.y * v.y`. It happens to also be equal to `||u|| * ||v|| * cos(angle(u,v))`, and one of its cool properties is that it is equal to 0 iff the two vectors are orthogonal. So it's an easy way to check that two vectors are orthogonal, given their coordinates.

Comment: @jojo_mark For your second question, the line you quoted is actually a typo on my part, it should be `table.setdefault(b - a, []).append((a, b))`. This is probably the most "pythonesque" line of all this code, so understanding this line requires understanding python and has not much to do with understanding vectors. Here `table` is a python dict, ie a hashtable. It maps vectors to lists of pairs of points. What this line does is add the pair of points `(a, b)` to the list of pairs of points that correspond to entry `b - a` in the hashtable.

Comment: @jojo_mark If you are going to implement this code in a language other than python, then perhaps there is no need to try to understand every line of `build_vector_table`, and instead just try to understand what `build_vector_table` does as a whole. Also note that this last algorithm is pretty much the same as the one presented by MattTimmermans in his answer, perhaps you'll find his explanation more clear than mine. The purpose of `table` in my code is the same as the purpose of "partition" in his explanation.

Comment: I see... though I do need to implement this in python LOL  
either way, one more question I have is about the line `for v, l in table`, I know in python you can loop over the keys and the items at the same time, is this like that? Could you explain what the v is and what the l is?
Thanks!

Comment: @jojo_mark It should be `for v, l in table.items():`, I edited to fix that about the same time as your comment :p. Here `v` is the key (so a vector) and `l` is the value (so a list of pairs of points).

Comment: @jojo_mark If you are going to implement this in python then one way is to use library numpy which knows how to deal with pairs of values being treated as vectors or points. for instance if you do `(4, 3) - (1, 1)` in python that's an error, but if you `import numpy as np` then `np.array([4, 3]) - np.array([1, 1])` correctly returns `np.array([3, 2])`. Also in numpy `dotproduct(u, v)` is `np.dot(u, v)` or `u.dot(v)` or `u @ v`. Also in numpy you can easily calculate the area of a quadrilateral using the cross product: `def area(a, b, c, d): return abs(np.cross(b - a, d - a).item()) / 2`

Comment: @jojo_mark Regarding `setdefault`, it's a convenient method of class `dict`, particularly useful when using a `dict` of lists to partition a list into sublists. `d.setdefault(k, []).append(x)` is equivalent to `if k in d: d[k].append(x); else: d[k] = [x]`.

Comment: @jojo_mark I have edited my answer so that it is now proper working python code.

Comment: Thank you! Though ofc I don't want to copy, so I may just implement my own N^3 solution.             
But this was very informative, I'll definitely try to use this method when I encounter similar problems in the future !

Comment: @jojo_mark Note that MattTimmermans suggests that the inner loop `for (a, b), (c, d) in combinations(l, 2):` is inefficient and can be optimised. Here `l` is a list of parallel pairs of points, and when you take two pairs of points that defines a parallelogram, but instead of iterating over all those possible parallelograms like I did, you can directly see that the largest possible parallelogram will consist of the lowest and highest or rightmost and leftmost pairs

Comment: @jojo_mark Also, the other optimisation that MattTimmermans did is that when building the table, instead of keeping all pairs, he only kept pairs (a, b) such that the angle between vector ab and the horizontal axis is between -45° and +45°. He can do that because if (a, b, c, d) is a rectangle, then either ab has an angle between -45 and +45, or ad has an angle between -45 and +45, and we don't need both. Also "ab has an angle between -45 and +45" is equivalent to "abs(by - ay) <= abs(bx - ax)"

Answer (score 5):

O(n^2) algorithm:

1. Generate all pairs of points `(p1,p2)` where `p1.x < p2.x` and the angle is <= 45 degrees and > -45 degrees.  Every rectangle will have a "top" and "bottom" side in this list.
2. Partition the pairs by angle and distance.  Every rectangle will have its top an bottom side in the same partition.
3. For each (angle,distance), partition the pairs by `p1.x*(p2.x-p1.x) + p1.y*(p2.y-p1.y)`.  Every rectangle will have its top and bottom side in the same partition, and every pair of pairs in each partition will make a rectangle.
4. For each resulting partition, find the points with min and max `p1.y`.  These make the largest rectangle in the partition.

Comment: I'm really happy because I *think* this is almost exactly the same algorithm as the one at the end of my answer :-)

Comment: Close, but that unnecessary `combinations` costs you.

Comment: Yes, I have a `combinations` that reflects explicitly your sentence "every pair of pairs in each partition will make a rectangle."; and I didn't implement point 4. "find the points with min and max p1.y"

Comment: when you say angle, do you mean the absolute angle relative to the x axis?
also I'm a tad confused about the "partitions", is it like a list of lists? How exactly is it sorted? Could you elaborate more on that?
thanks!

Comment: Yes, the absolute angle w.r.t. the x axis.  "Partitioning by x" means that you divide the list into sublists, where each sublists contains all the items with the same value of x.  partitioning by "angle and distance" is the same as partitioning by `(p2.x-p1.x, p2.y-p1.y)`.